# Strange thing in clear command

Tags: bash, shell

Today I was just experimenting with Linux shell. Here is what I did.

1. I wrote the output of clear to a file :

   ```
   clear > clear.txt
   ```
2. Now I have some contents on the shell, (non-empty). Then I try to `cat` the contents of `clear.txt`

   ```
   cat clear.txt
   ```

For my surprise, the entire screen got cleared. Can somone explain me why? if this is true, why cant we do the same for all the commands?

Comment: _why cant we do the same for all the commands?_ : I don't understand this question. Can you give as an example a command, where you want to see a similar effect, but don't get it?

Comment: I meant to ask, how is clear so unique.

Comment: In what respect is it unique? Which command would behave in a different way? I can not see anything special with this command.

Answer (score 2):

`clear` works very simply by transmitting a sequence of control codes which are interpreted by your terminal. The magic of actually clearing the screen is handled by your terminal (or terminal emulator, or console interface, or whatever you happen to be using) in response to receiving these control codes.

See also e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not a real explanation but it's how it is supposed to work:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/clear.1.html

```
   @CLEAR@ writes to the standard output.  You can redirect the standard
   output to a file (which prevents @CLEAR@ from actually clearing the
   screen), and later cat the file to the screen, clearing it at that
   point.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a visual representation of the clear command. Editing the text file yields:

```
^[[3J^[[H^[[2J
```

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400142/terminal-h2j-caret-square-bracket-h-caret-square-bracket-2-j